# Why does liblzma fail to compress any random string?

Tags: string, random, compression, complexity-theory

I'm using the ruby binding, `ruby-xz`.

```
random_string = SecureRandom.random_bytes(100)
compressed_string = XZ.compress(random_string, compression_level = 9, check = :none, extreme = true)
compressed_string.size # => always 148
```

I've tested it ten thousands of times, on strings of varying length.

I know that at least half of the strings are 1-incompressible (cannot be compresse by more than 1 bit), 3/4 of the strings are 2-incompressible, etc. (This follows from a counting argument.) This, obviously, says nothing about the lower bound of the number compressible strings, but there are bound to be a few, aren't there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

There are a few reasons:

1. liblzma, when not in RAW mode, adds a header describing the dictionary size and a few other settings. That is one of the reasons it grows in size.
2. LZMA, like a lot of other compressors, uses a range encoder to encode the output of the dictionary compression (in essence a badass version of LZ77) in the least amount of bits needed. So at the end of the bit stream, the last bits are padded to make it into a full byte.
3. You are compressing random noise, which as you note, is hard to compress. The range encoder tries to find the least amount of bits to encode the symbols outputted by the dictionary compression round. So in this case, there will be a lot of symbols. If, there was one (or two) recurring patterns that LZMA found, it could be that in the end it only saves a bit or two from the output. Which as explained in point 2, you cannot observe on a byte level.

## Experiment

Some small experiments for observing the overhead.

#### empty file with lzma in raw mode:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1k count=0 2>/dev/null | xz -9 -e --format=raw -c 2>/dev/null | wc -c
       1
```

it needed at least one or two bits to say it reached the end of the stream, and this was padded to one byte

#### 1k file filled with zeroes

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1k count=1 2>/dev/null | xz -9 -e --format=raw -c 2>/dev/null | wc -c
      19
```

quite nice, but complexity theory wise, still perhaps a few bytes to many (1000x'\0' would have been optimal encoding)

#### 1k file with all bits at 1

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1k count=1 2>/dev/null | sed 's/\x00/\xFF/g'| xz -9 -e --format=raw -c 2>/dev/null | wc -c
      21
```

interestingly, xz compresses this a little worse than all zeroes. most likely related to the fact that LZMA dictionary works on a bit level (which was one of the novel ideas of LZMA).

#### 1k random file:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1k count=1 2>/dev/null | xz -9 -e --format=raw -c 2>/dev/null | wc -c
    1028
```

so 4 bytes more than the input, still not bad.

#### 1000 runs of 1k random files:

```
$ for i in {1..1000}; do dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1k count=1 2>/dev/null | xz -9 -e --format=raw -c 2>/dev/null | wc -c; done | sort | uniq -c
1000     1028
```

so every time, 1028 bytes needed.